# how to upload multiple image in my backend module joomla form

Tags: php, joomla

I am developing a module in Joomla 3.x and want to add a browse button on the backend so the user can pick a file they have previously uploaded but when I use a media type in the mod_module_name.xml I can upload only one picture.

I use the code below in a xml file but I can upload only one picture? How would I go about this?

```
               <field
                    name="image_intro"
                    type="media"
                    label="Select an Image"
                    description=""
                    class="inputbox" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When uploading, you **can** upload multiple images at the same time. When you click "Browse", you can select multiple images to be uploaded by holding **CTRL** on the keyboard and selecting your chosen images.

### Update

The above only applies when **uploading**. If you are referring to selecting an image, what I would recommend doing is allowing the user to type in the directory of where the images have been uploaded to. Then in your module, you get the directory value and get all the images from there.

So in your XML file, use the following:

```
<field
    name="directory"
    type="text"
    default="images/yourfolder"
    label="Type in your image directory"
    description=""
    class="inputbox" />
```

Then assuming the user has typed in `images/customfolder`, you can use the following which will display all images from that folder:

```
<?php 
    $directory = $params->get('directory');
    $path = JPATH_SITE . '/' . $directory;
    $exclude = array('index.html');
    $images = JFolder::files($path, '.', null, null, $exclude );

    foreach($images as $image)
    {
        echo '<img src="' . JUri::root() . $directory . '/' . $image . '" alt="" />';
    }
?>
```

As you can see, I have excluded the *index.html* and you can add more excludes to the array.

The user will of course be expected to upload the images using Joomla's Media Manager.

Comment: This in not possible in 'media' type. It only gives one image to choose.

Comment: That means, the user should enter the directory name in a textbox? Or, what else should I do? Can you please provide a snippet of code?

Comment: @Puran - I have provided a code example for you. Tested and working

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 3.9.x use the File form field type and specify multiple=true. See https://docs.joomla.org/File_form_field_type

```
<field name="images"
   type="file"
   label="Select image(s) to upload"
   description="Choose one or more images from your computer"
   size="10"
   multiple="true"
/>
```